# Groups Annotations don't works

Tags: php, rest, serialization, symfony, fosrestbundle

Symfony 3.1.7 + FOSRestBundle latest version

```
<?php
namespace PM\ApiBundle\Controller;

...
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

class ArticlesController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @ApiDoc(
     *  section="articles",
     *  resource=true,
     *  description="Get articles published"
     * )
     * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"article"})
     * @Rest\Get("/articles")
     */
    public function getArticlesAction(Request $request)
    {
        $articles = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('PMPlatformBundle:Article')
            ->findAllDateDesc();
        /* @var $articles Article[] */
        return $articles;
    }
```

Then in my Article entity I added this annotation @Groups({"article"}) with the right use statement.

Whit default serializer I get :

```
[
    [],
    []
]
```

Whit JMS serializer (bundle) I get :

```
{
    "0": {},
    "1": {}
}
```

(I have two articles in db)
 it seems like the "article" group is not recognized. When I use the default serializer whithout this annotations I get a circular error.

What's wrong ?

[EDIT] Same behavior with

```
/**
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  section="articles",
 *  resource=true,
 *  description="Get articles published"
 * )
 * @Rest\View()
 * @Rest\Get("/articles")
 */
public function getArticlesAction(Request $request)
{
    $context = new Context();
    $context->addGroup('article');

    $articles = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('PMPlatformBundle:Article')
        ->findAllDateDesc();
    /* @var $articles Article[] */
    $view = $this->view($articles, 200);
    $view->setContext($context);

    return $view;
}
```

The response still empty.

Comment: Can you please tell us what your findAllDateDesc() method returns (var_dump or print_r) / Can you please paste code of your entity or serializer configuration ?

Comment: My method findAllDateDesc() works fine (and for debbuging, god ! dont use var_dump or print_r, personnaly I use xdebug..), my entity is not the problem here, serializer cong too. I answered my question, I fix this problem with JMS serializer. Any way thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I fixed it using JMS serializer like this :

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder;


class ArticlesController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @ApiDoc(
     *  section="articles",
     *  resource=true,
     *  description="Get articles published"
     * )
     * @Rest\View()
     * @Rest\Get("/articles")
     */
    public function getArticlesAction(Request $request)
    {
        $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();

        $articles = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('PMPlatformBundle:Article')
            ->findAllDateDesc();
        /* @var $articles Article[] */


        return $serializer->serialize($articles, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('article')));
    }
```

Now the groups annotations works fine.

Comment: you can get the jmsSerializer service with $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer.serializer')

Answer (score 6):

You can keep the default serializer of symfony. No need of JMSSerializer.

You may have forgotten to activate the annotations of serializer in config.yml (https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations)

```
#app/config/config.yml
framework:
    ....
    serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
```

It is necessary to force the view_response_listener in config.yml  (http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/3-listener-support.html, http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/view_response_listener.html)

```
#app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
```

That should work !

Answer (score 1):

try `php bin/console cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Using your suggested answer

```
$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
return $serializer->serialize($collection, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(['group']));
```

returns JSON as string to me. To solve your problem, you have to have the following in your `config.yml` file:

```
jms_serializer:
  metadata:
    auto_detection: true
```

this is how it recognises mappings that you specify with your annotations in Entity files. More info on it here: [docs](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/configuration#extension-reference). Having that, you can use the `@View(serializerGroups={"group"})` annotation as you wanted.

P.S. Symfony 3.2.2; JMSSerializer 1.1; FOSRestBundle 2.1